# Split function not working properly inside Recyclerview Adapter

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am using a split function inside a RecyclerView Adapter to split a String separated by comma although the code works fine inside the activity. But inside the recycler view Adapter, it is giving different answers I am getting data from firebase Firestore.

My Code

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Adapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

     Colours =products.getColour();
        String[] values = Colours.split(",");

        switch (values.length) {

            case 1 : {
                Colour1 = values[0];
                break;
            }

            case 2 : {
                Colour1=values[0];
                Colour2=values[1];
                break;

            }

            case 3 : {
                Colour1=values[0];
                Colour2=values[1];
                Colour3=values[2];
                break;
            }

            case 4 : {
                Colour1=values[0];
                Colour2=values[1];
                Colour3=values[2];
                Colour4=values[3];
                break;

            }

            case 5 :{
                Colour1=values[0];
                Colour2=values[1];
                Colour3=values[2];
                Colour4=values[3];
                Colour5=values[4];
                break;

            }

            case 6:{
                Colour1=values[0];
                Colour2=values[1];
                Colour3=values[2];
                Colour4=values[3];
                Colour5=values[4];
                Colour6=values[5];
                break;

            }

        }
    Log.d(TAG,"Colours are : "+Colour1+Colour2+Colour3+Colour4+Colour5+Colour6);

}
```

Actual values inside Colour String are

"-7941431,-9522231"

"-16183539"

"-13680981,-1813697,-5554626,-5144272,-47523"

"-11582057"

"-2975686"

Values  I get after splitting

```
D/MyTag: Colours are : -7941431-9522231
D/MyTag: Colours are : -16183539-9522231
D/MyTag: Colours are : -13680981-1813697-5554626-5144272-47523
D/MyTag: Colours are : -11582057-1813697-5554626-5144272-47523
D/MyTag: Colours are : -2975686-1813697-5554626-5144272-47523
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are not resetting other variables so it is showing old values, so try this:

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Adapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Colours =products.getColour();
        Colour1 = "";
        Colour2 = "";
        Colour3 = "";
        Colour4 = "";
        Colour5 = "";
        Colour6 = "";
        String[] values = Colours.split(",");

        switch (values.length) {

            case 1 : {
                Colour1 = values[0];
                break;
            }

            case 2 : {
                Colour1=values[0];
                Colour2=values[1];
                break;

            }

            case 3 : {
                Colour1=values[0];
                Colour2=values[1];
                Colour3=values[2];
                break;
            }

            case 4 : {
                Colour1=values[0];
                Colour2=values[1];
                Colour3=values[2];
                Colour4=values[3];
                break;

            }

            case 5 :{
                Colour1=values[0];
                Colour2=values[1];
                Colour3=values[2];
                Colour4=values[3];
                Colour5=values[4];
                break;

            }

            case 6:{
                Colour1=values[0];
                Colour2=values[1];
                Colour3=values[2];
                Colour4=values[3];
                Colour5=values[4];
                Colour6=values[5];
                break;

            }

        }
    Log.d(TAG,"Colours are : "+Colour1+Colour2+Colour3+Colour4+Colour5+Colour6);

}
```